# How to rsync a directory to a new directory with different name?

Tags: rsync

I'm doing a data transfer, the old file system relies deeply on a directory which now is on different path. This is a git directory which stores code online. I have no rights to move it or rename it.

So what I can do is rsync this directory to the same old path. But the directory name also changed.

Is there a easy way that I can rsync a directory to a target directory with a different name?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

If you want to use `rsync` to recursively make the `dest` directory an exact copy of the `src` directory:

```
rsync -a src/ dest
```

The `rsync` man page explains how this works:

> A trailing slash on the source [...] avoid[s] creating an additional directory level at the destination.  You can think of a trailing `/` on a source as meaning  "copy the contents of this directory" as opposed to "copy the directory by name" [...]

Comment: This will create an `src` directory under `dest` directory

Comment: @Zen, not in any version of `rsync` I've ever used. If that's actually happening to you, you're missing the trailing slash at the end of the source directory argument.

Comment: That sneaky trailing slash is KEY...

Comment: unfortunately this does not seem to work if `dest` is a symlnk to `src`, it instead ends up copying `src` to `src/src`. Tested on macOS. Was hoping that I could replace `bar -> foo/` with `bar/`, but had to use an intermediate temporary directory.

Comment: @user5359531 If you know that `dest` is a symlink to `src`, simply `rm dest` before running the above command. `rsync` is smart enough to create `dest` before copying the contents of `src`. You don't need an intermediate temp dir.

Comment: If you are using `rsync` for Windows from Cygwin then `-a` wouldn't work correctly. `-a` implies a few options including `-pgo`. It changes target folder's permission and you can't use it. Use command `icacls dest /T /Q /C /RESET` to reset persmissions. My command is looking as the following `rsync -rlt src/ dest`.

Comment: I've solved this problem at least 15 times in my life ... it's just not intuitive enough to be remembered well.

Comment: Note that the directory `dest` doesn't have to exist already for this to work.

Answer (score 19):

## Quick Start

Run:

```
rsync -av --exclude='path1/in/source' --exclude='path2/in/source' [source]/ [destination]
```

---

### Notes

- `-avr` will create a new directory named `[destination]`.
- `source` and `source/` create different results:

  - `source` — copy the *folder* source into destination.
  - `source/` — copy the *contents* of source into destination.
- To exclude many files:

  - `--exclude-from=FILE` — `FILE` is the name of a file containing other files or directories to exclude.
- `--exclude` may also contain wildcards:

  - e.g. `--exclude=*/.svn*`

Modified from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2194500/749232

---

## Example

Starting folder structure:

```
.
├── destination
└── source
    ├── fileToCopy.rtf
    └── fileToExclude.rtf
```

Run:

```
rsync -av --exclude='fileToCopy.rtf' source/ destination
```

Ending folder structure:

```
.
├── destination
│   └── fileToExclude.rtf
└── source
    ├── fileToCopy.rtf
    └── fileToExclude.rtf
```

Comment: What are `path1` and `path2`?  Why do you believe that `--exclude` is relevant to this question? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: in case someone needs stats and progress follow this. https://askubuntu.com/a/908022/123217

Answer (score 2):

If the old and new filesystems are both accessible to your machine, then consider using a symbolic link instead of rsync. If your rsync command you're using does not specify hosts (or if they are the same host), then this is the case. You're trying to mirror two directories with a different name on the same host. Don't use rsync for this, since you are duplicating the data, and you will have to run your rsync often to keep them in sync.

Using a symbolic link is a one-time fix that will mirror two directories (with different names) and requires almost no space. It's like creating an alias directory that points to another directory.

Let's say you had the old git in a directory called /old/path/old_git and now the code repository has moved to /new/path/new_git

You can do:

```
cd /old/path
rm -rf old_git     (if you still have it there, get rid of it, or move it out of the way)  
ln -s /new/path/new_git old_git
```

This will create a link as such:

/old/path/old_git -> /new/path/new_git

So that anything that is put into new_git will be instantly available the old way as well, without duplicating data, and without having to constantly sync them.

Comment: Be careful with the rm -rf old_git command. This will remove your entire old_git repository. If I'm not understanding your problem right, this could be a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

I find an alternative solution now.

Using `rysnc -r /origin/* /target/` can  sync all the contents from origin directory to target directory.

Comment: I believe this doesn't include dot (.foo) files because these will not be matched with the asterisk

Comment: that relies on shell glob expansion, technically it will pass every file found there as an argument to rsync. it is almost the same as running `rsync -r $(find /origin -maxdepth 1 -type f) /target/ `. As @RayBurgemeestre pointed out, shell glob expansion won't include dot files.